# Cloud SQL v1beta4API is to access Cloud SQL Database Info or Database Data?

Tags: android, database, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is `Cloud SQL v1beta4API` is to access `Cloud SQL Database Instance` or `Database Data` if this is only to access Database Information then how to access/Query data in the database from an Android client application or any other application?

Comment: Cloud SQL API is to access/manage the Cloud SQL instance and not for database queries. You will need to use a SQL driver in your program.

Comment: So there is no way to query using REST API? any tutorials? @JohnHanley

Comment: I am not an Android developer, but there are many articles, etc on the Internet. The driver that you need depends on the database (MySQL/PostgreSQL). Developing your own driver takes a huge amount of work. Use a published library. Note: connecting from an Android device directly to a database server is not a good security idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud SQL Admin API is for administrative tasks in managing an instance. It can start, stop, create, or perform other administrative task to an instance.

If you want to build a REST api to access the data, I would suggest using something like Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.

Comment: Is Cloud Endpoints different from Cloud Functions ? @kurtisvg

Comment: and found this link `https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql` to connect Cloud SQL through Cloud Functions, this is how to do?

Comment: Yes, they are different. [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) is a utility service for helping to monitor and protect your api. [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) is a hosted environment that allows you to deploy a single function as an http endpoint. You can write a different function for each endpoint of your REST API. These endpoints can receive http requests, perform the appropriate query, and return the data to the caller.